# Bootstrap indicators don't work on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When slide changes indicators are in right position (1-2-3). But when I click on them, they are not responding. Prev and next links are working fine. Here is my code:

```
<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel-slide hidden-xs" data-interval ="3000">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img class="img-responsive" src="eberhard-grossgasteiger-311213.jpg" alt="slide 1"></div>
            <div class="item"><img class="d-block img-fluid" src="annie-spratt-176376.jpg" alt="slide 2"></div>
            <div class="item"><img class="d-block img-fluid" src="joanna-kosinska-129039.jpg" alt="slide 3"></div>
        </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->
        <!-- navigation -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div><!-- /carousel-slide --
```

Here is JS file:

```
// Activate Carouse
$("#theCarousel").carousel();

// Enable Carousel Indicators
$(".item").click(function(){
    $("#theCarousel").carousel(1);
 });

// Enable Carousel Control
 $(".left").click(function(){
     $("#theCarousel").carousel("prev");
 });

 $(".right").click(function(){
     $("#theCarousel").carousel("next");
 });
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click button "Run code snippet" and check its working, No need to add extra script(js), All controls of carousel handled by bootstrap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, but when i removed js file, problem persists.

Comment: I have copy/pasted your code, put in my pictures, and it works. Now i'm interested what was different in my code, that was keeping indicators from working.  My carousel wasn't inside .container, and data-interval was different. can anybody tell me what was wrong?

Comment: I finally found out what went wrong. Instead of two classes: `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> ` i wrote one with hyphen between: `<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel-slide hidden-xs" data-interval ="3000">`

Comment: Ok fine, I am glade to see, Its working for you. Please upvote my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what went wrong. Instead of two classes: `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` i wrote one with hyphen between: `<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel-slide hidden-xs" data-interval ="3000">`.